# Problems with threading library, print function and Thread.join() method

Tags: python

i hope you guys can help me because has been two days that i on this thing. probably i'm stupid, but i can't get this. so, i'm studying this piece of code (taken from this video: https://youtu.be/StmNWzHbQJU) and i just modified the function called by Threading class.

```
import threading
from time import sleep
from random import choice

def doThing():
    threadId = choice([i for i in range(1000)]) # just 'names' a thread
    while True:
        print(f"{threadId} ", flush=True)
        sleep(3)
        
threads = []

for i in range(50):
    t = threading.Thread(target=doThing, daemon = False)
    threads.append(t)

for i in range(50):
    threads[i].start()

for i in range(50):
    threads[i].join()
```

the problems are basically 3:

1. i can't stop the program with ctrl+c like he does in the video. i tried by set daemon = False or delet the .join() loop, nothing work, neither in the Idle interpeter neithe in the command line and powershell (i'm on windows);
2. as i said,i tried to set daemon=False and to delete the .join() loop, but nothing change during the execution so i'm a little bit confused on what "daemon" and ".join()" actually does;
3. the function doThing() is endless so the join() shouldn't be useful. And i don't understand why there are two "for" loops, one for start() and one for join(). Can't they be into
   the same "for" cycle?
4. last thing, the print output is totally different between Idle and powershell: in Idle i get some lines with different numbers, in the powershell i get only one number per line (look at the images):https://ibb.co/HtMr9gf, https://ibb.co/Y8gzDtw, but in visual code, which use powershell too, i get this: https://ibb.co/X82vY3v

can you help me to understand this please? i'm really confused. thank you a lot

Answer (score 0):

1. You have to use ctrl+c multiple time to end all threads or close the terminal, **but you have to set DAEMON = True** for each thread (...for daemon thread [read here](https://superfastpython.com/daemon-threads-in-python/))
2. .join() waits for all the threads end to go over in the function and execute the code after your for loop with .join()...for daemon thread [read here](https://superfastpython.com/daemon-threads-in-python/)
3. join() and start() can't be in the same loop. You have to start all threads first. Then you are saying to wait the end of all threads to continue executing the function with join()... it's like you are setting the function in stand-by waiting for all threaded operations end
4. Don't know differences between idle and powershell... but (without debugging your code, only reading it) I think should be right one number per line in the output.

EDIT:

Q: *3. why can't i? in the for loop i can start a thread and than join it, and this for 50 times. what am i missing?*

A: Cause doing that you are executing one thread per time and not simultaneously, eg.:

(Func A() and B() are threaded functions)

**Example with start() and join() in the same for loop:**

```
func main() --> Start 

func A() --> Executing 

func A() --> Completed 

func B() --> Executing 

func B() --> Completed 

func main() --> Continue
```

**Example with start() and join() in different for loop:**

```
func main() --> Start

func A() --> Executing

func B() --> Executing

func A() --> Completed

func B() --> Completed

func main() --> Continue
```

**EDIT 2**
Q: last thing, the print output is totally different between Idle and powershell: in Idle i get some lines with different numbers, in the powershell i get only one number per line (look at the images):https://ibb.co/HtMr9gf, https://ibb.co/Y8gzDtw, but in visual code, which use powershell too, i get this: https://ibb.co/X82vY3v

**In my terminal, also in VSCode I got one number per line....don't know how you could get multiple numbers per line in the output....**

Comment: 1. he just use one ctrl+c to stop the execution. i tried to press it numerous time but it doesn't stop the execution on my pc. 
3. why can't i? in the for loop i can start a thread and than join it, and this for 50 times. what am i missing?
4. let's see if someone else can explain this strange thing

Comment: If you have 50 threads, you need to press Ctrl+C 50 times, too …

Comment: Edited answer with your new questions

Comment: @TheEagle i pressed it hundreds of time and the program still run. when i tried it on linux it stopped, but it stop the second time i press ctrl+c. the first time it tries to stop ("Keyboard Interrupted" show up on the terminal), but immediately start again the execution. the second time that i press ctrl+c it stops for good

Comment: @Xrayman i just read your modification, thank you. i don't know why it prints in different ways. on linux it prints on one line. besides, as i wrote above, i pressed it hundreds of time and the program still ran on windows. when i tried it on linux it stopped, but it stop the second time i press ctrl+c. the first time it tries to stop ("Keyboard Interrupted" show up on the terminal), but immediately start again the execution. the second time that i press ctrl+c it stops for good. do you know why?

Comment: Yes, that's an issue (bug) in windows explained here https://bugs.python.org/issue35935


Please set the answer as completed, thank you!